# Android-viewflow with ListItems

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I'm using the android-viewflow library (https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) to enable horizontal paging. On each page, I would like to display a ListView of data, different for each page.

The general implementation questions I have are:

1. Will I need to create a separate adapter for each ListView on each page or use the same adapter, feed it different data for each page and "Android just knows what to do with it" when I page left/right?
2. I'm struggling with the getView method of the adapter that is used for the horizontal paging (not the list view). As I switch pages left/right, I think  getView is where I need to implement code that retrieves data to be shown and puts it in the listview on that page. Is this correct or do I need to handle things differently?

Any help is appreciated on understanding this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html). Here is an [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html)

Comment: I'm starting to dig into fragments to understand them better. Do you have any feel for the performance of an app that might have a dozen pages each with its own fragment that hosts a listview of items? Thank you for the link, I will attempt this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the ViewPager support class rather than ViewFlow for horizontal paging. It's more flexible and easier to use. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: I thought ViewPager only supported a fixed number of pages, where you cannot add/remove pages. This incorrect?

Comment: ViewPager takes an PagerAdapter, which can have Views added to it dynamically.